# regex matching any character including spaces

Tags: regex

Howto regex for matching a string, which contains characters and spaces ?

Text:

```
Blabla === This is my Text === Blablabla
```

My Regex so far:

```
===(.?)===
```

I would like to simply match:

```
=== This is my Text ===
```

Comment: .? means a character 0 or 1 time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
===(.*?)===
```

You missed the `*` or the quantifier.`+` is the other quantfier.

Comment: @dystroy left coz not sure if OP wants a greedy or non greedy one....to be safe used non greedy