# Python regex finding and repositioning words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**SOLVED**

---

I have previously been using the console.snips.ai console to make and train my assistant but now I'm looking to self run it locally without all the other features and need to change the format of the exported file that the console gives you. It needs changing from : `how tall is [Bill Gates](queryObject) [uncle](relations)` to `how tall is [queryObject](Bill Gates) [relations](uncle)` and then that can be easily put into the yaml format needed.

So far I have been able to flip the type of brackets surrounding the entity - `queryObject` and entity example `Bill Gates` with some very long and drawn out code below, but I am struggling to flip the position of `(Bill Gates)` and `[queryObject]` with there nearest one so `Bill Gates` and `queryObject` would swap and the same with `relations` and `uncle`

```
string_ = "how tall is [Bill Gates](queryObject) [uncle](relations)"

nStr = list(string_)

for i , char in enumerate(nStr):

if char == "[":

    nStr[i] = "{"

if char == "]":

    nStr[i] = "}"

if char == "(":

    nStr[i] = "["

if char == ")":

   nStr[i] = "]"

for j , char in enumerate(nStr):

    if char == "{":

        nStr[j] = "("

    if char == "}":

        nStr[j] = ")"

new = ''.join(nStr)

print(new)
```

So this successfully turns `how tall is [Bill Gates](queryObject) [uncle](relations)` to `how tall is (Bill Gates)[queryObject] (uncle)[relations]`.

But how do I flip the positions of `()` with the `[]` nearest to it.

## UPDATED

THIS IS WHAT IS HAPPENING NOW

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References: 
[regex matching any character including spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856571/regex-matching-any-character-including-spaces)

Code:

```
import re
new = 'how tall is [Bill Gates](queryObject) [uncle](relations)'
result = (re.sub(r'(\[.*?\])(\(.*?\))', r'\2\1', new))
print(result)
```

Will change:

```
how tall is [Bill Gates](queryObject) [uncle](relations)
```

To:

```
how tall is (queryObject)[Bill Gates] (relations)[uncle]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub()` with backreference:

```
import re

s = 'how tall is [Bill Gates](queryObject) [uncle](relations)'

result = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)', r'[\2](\1)', s)

# how tall is [queryObject](Bill Gates) [relations](uncle)
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work, I get the same result printing ``new`` and ``result``

Comment: @LJ_Samurai, Isn't this `'how tall is [queryObject](Bill Gates) [relations](uncle)'` your expected output?

Comment: yes, it is, I will update my explanation to show what is happening.